# Tomcat https redirect (security-constraint) for different host

Tags: tomcat, https, security-constraint

I am trying to redirect the calls from http to https so:

In my server.xml I have two host:

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
 ...
  </Host>
  <Host name="other.name" appBase="/srv/webapp" 
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
  ...
  </Host>
```

And I added on /etc/tomcat7/web.xml:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Protected Context</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
   <user-data-constraint>
       <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
   </user-data-constraint>
 </security-constraint>
```

So all request that are going to the localhost host are being redirect to https, however the requests that are going to other.name are not being redirect.

What I want is only the request that are going to other.name be redirect to https, how can I do that?

I tried to put

```
<url-pattern>other.name/*</url-pattern>
```

but didn't work. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I removed the `<security-constraint>` from `/etc/tomcat7/web.xml` and added to the `WEB-INF/web.xml` of my web application.

Comment: Yes, I removed the <security-constraint> from /etc/tomcat7/web.xml and added to the WEB-INF/web.xml of my web application